# Некорректное отображение блока на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css

Есть верстка
 HTML

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <div id="page" class="site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
      <div class="site-branding">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="logo alignleft">
                <a class="logo_img" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
                   <img src="<?php the_field('main_logo', 41); ?>" alt="Логотип"></a>           
            </div>

            <div class="logo_text">
                <p><?php the_field('logo_text', 41); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="contact_side">
            <?php
                $phone = get_field('phone', 41);
                $vowels = array("+", "(", ")", " ", "-", "_");                  
                $truephone = str_replace($vowels, "", $phone);
            ?>
                <a class="phone" href="tel:<?= $truephone ?>"><img src="<?php echo(get_template_directory_uri())?>/images/tel.png" alt=""><?php the_field('phone', 41); ?></a><br>
                <a class="modal_btn_call" href="#callback_modal">Заказать звонок</a><br>
                <a class="mail_me" href="mailto:<?php the_field('email', 41); ?>"><?php the_field('email', 41); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .site-branding -->

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">          
        <div class="container">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
        ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 1140px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;    
}
.logo {
    height: 143px;
}

.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.logo_text {
    display: inline-block;
}
.contact_side {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fecc00;
    height: 60px;
}
```

На главной странице сайта шапка ведет себя адекватно на всех устройствах. Проблема в том, что на остальных страницах сайта шапка на мобильных устройствах не масштабируется под ширину экрана устройства. Viewportr отключен. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без вьюпорта стандартная ширина экранов всех мобильных устройств в портретной или ланшавтной ориентации ровна 960px вне зависимотсти от диагонали или разрешения экрана самого устроства, а у тебя `width: 1140px !important;`